# Locate the last used cell of row in an Excel sheet

Tags: excel, delphi

I am developing an application that modifies an Excel file.

How can I locate the last used cell on any row?

**example : last used cell in Row Number => 5**

Comment: Does [`Worksheet.UsedRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) help?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My guess is that would return the outer bounds of used cells, which may differ per row. But if he were to replace worksheet with a range restricted to the row he's interested in, that is probably exactly what he needs.

Comment: @MarjanVenema `UsedRange` on not available on a `Range`, just `Worksheet`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: dang, too bad

Comment: Found it: Range.End property: "Returns a Range object that represents the cell at the end of the region that contains the source range. Equivalent to pressing END+UP ARROW, END+DOWN ARROW, END+LEFT ARROW, or END+RIGHT ARROW. Read-only Range object." See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839539.aspx

Answer (score 3):

To locate the last cell in a row you need the `End` property of a `Range`.

As per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839539.aspx):

> Returns a Range object that represents the cell at the end of the
>   region that contains the source range. Equivalent to pressing END+UP
>   ARROW, END+DOWN ARROW, END+LEFT ARROW, or END+RIGHT ARROW. Read-only
>   Range object.

For example (VB code)

```
Range("B4").End(xlToRight)
```

would move the current cell to the last cell before the first empty cell to the right of B4

```
Range("B4").End(xlToRight).Select
```

would select that cell.

Note

Just bear in mind though that you may need to do this several times when you are dealing with a worksheet that has empty cells in the row you are doing this on. End+Right only moves to the "last non-empty before the first empty cell" starting from the current. If there are other non-empty cells after that first empty cell, you will have to do repeat. The last non-empty cell would thus be the one before the "End" that returns the absolute last column in the sheet.

Comment: Thank you ,

But how i convert this Visual Basic code to Delphi code ?

Comment: @user2227547: Really? This code is simply using the Excel COM automation model. Either use late binding and pretty much copy the VB code (just some fiddling with the quotes), or use the automation components that come with Delphi and work from the ActiveSheet property of the ExcelApplication. [Deborah Pate's page on Excel automation](http://www.djpate.freeserve.co.uk/AutoExcl.htm) should also help.

Comment: @  Marjan Venema : thank you! this is my delphi code: 'ExcelApp.ActiveSheet.Range['B4'].End(xlToRight).Select ;' is don't work ! i have a error msg.

Comment: yes you can't see my computer :this is the msg error:"member not found".

Comment: @Bill, Marjan's answer says `Range('B4')`, not `Range['B4']`. They're parentheses `()`, not square brackets `[]` around the `'B4'`.

Comment: @Bill: Always quote the exact and full error message. What member is not found? When does the error happen, at compile or at run time? If you want us to help, please provide us with all the information needed to do so. [Question checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx)

Comment: @KenWhite: Yes, but it is a VB code example, so Bill's use of parentheses may well have been inspired by code insight. (I did tell him to work his way in from ActiveSheet...)